# Error NameError

Tags: variables, python-3.7, names

Hola chicos soy nueva en python y estoy tratando de hacer un medidor del angulo que existe entre dos centroides de figuras de distintos colores. Primero realizo la localización de los centroides de figuras azules y veres,posteriormente deseo que entre los centroides de las dos figuras localizadas se dibuje una linea recta, he consultado código de los programadores Hindu y muy amablemente me los facilitaron, he seguido su sintaxis y en su mayoría es lo mismo que hago yo en mi código.

Sin embargo cuando trato de dibujar una linea entre los centroides, no me reconoce una variable y no sé por qué, he tratado con funciones y con variables globales, pero no he podido identificar el problema. Solicito de su amable guía pues soy nueva tanto en OpenCV como en Python, cualquier pista podría ser de gran ayuda de ante mano les agradezco.

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
height = 640
width  = 480

while(1):
        ret,frame = cap.read()
        hsv = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)

         #Establecemos el rango de colores que vamos a detectar
    #En este caso de verde oscuro a verde-azulado claro
        verde_bajos = np.array([49,50,50], dtype=np.uint8) 
        verde_altos = np.array([80, 255, 255], dtype=np.uint8)
        azul_bajos  = np.array([100,100,20],dtype=np.uint8)
        azul_altos  = np.array([125,255,255],dtype=np.uint8)

    #Crear una mascara con solo los pixeles dentro del rango de verdes
        mask = cv2.inRange(hsv, verde_bajos, verde_altos)
        mask1 = cv2.inRange(hsv, azul_bajos, azul_altos) 

        # Kernel para transformaciones morfologicas
        kernel = np.ones((5, 5)) 

                # Transformaciones morfológicas para eliminar el ruido que se obtiene en la imagen
        dilacion = cv2.dilate(mask, kernel, iterations=1)
        erosion = cv2.erode(dilacion, kernel, iterations=1)
        dilacion1 = cv2.dilate(mask1, kernel, iterations=1)
        erosion1 = cv2.erode(dilacion1, kernel, iterations=1)
                # Filtro gaussiano y se aplica un umbral de otsu
        filtrado = cv2.GaussianBlur(erosion, (5, 5), 0)
        filtrado1 = cv2.GaussianBlur(erosion1, (5, 5), 0)
                # ~ ret, thresh = cv2.threshold(filtrado, 127, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)
        ret, thresh = cv2.threshold(filtrado, 127, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY+cv2.THRESH_OTSU)
        ret1, thresh1 = cv2.threshold(filtrado1, 127, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY+cv2.THRESH_OTSU)

        #cv2.imshow(windowName,frame)
        #cv2.imshow(windowName1,thresh)

        # Detección de contornos
        contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(thresh, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
        contours1, hierarchy1= cv2.findContours(thresh1, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL,cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)

        for c in contours:
            area = cv2.contourArea(c)
            if area > 1000:
                M = cv2.moments(c)  #centroide
                if (M["m00"]==0): M["m00"]=1
                x = int(M["m10"]/M["m00"])
                y = int(M['m01']/M['m00'])
                cv2.circle(frame, (x,y), 7, (0,255,0), -1)#dibuja circulo en el centroide
                font = cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX
                cv2.putText(frame, '{},{}'.format(x,y),(x+10,y), font, 0.75,(0,255,0),1,cv2.LINE_AA)
                nuevoContorno = cv2.convexHull(c)
                cv2.drawContours(frame, [nuevoContorno], 0, (255,0,0), 3)
                cv2.line(frame,(x, y),((height, width)[0], y),(0, 255, 0), 1, cv2.LINE_AA)

        for i in contours1:
                area1 = cv2.contourArea(i)
                if area1 > 1000:
                    M = cv2.moments(i)  #centroide
                    if (M["m00"]==0): M["m00"]=1
                    x1 = int(M["m10"]/M["m00"])
                    y1 = int(M['m01']/M['m00'])
                    cv2.circle(frame, (x1,y1), 7, (0,0,255), -1)#dibuja circulo en el centroide
                    font = cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX
                    cv2.putText(frame, '{},{}'.format(x1,y1),(x1+10,y1), font, 0.75,(0,255,0),1,cv2.LINE_AA)
                    nuevoContorno = cv2.convexHull(i)
                    cv2.drawContours(frame, [nuevoContorno], 0, (255,0,0), 3)
                    cv2.line(frame,(x, y), (x1, y1),(0, 255, 0), 1, cv2.LINE_AA)
#        x = float(x)
#        y = float(y)
#        x1 = float(x1)
#        y1 = float(y1)
#      


        cv2.imshow('frame',frame)
        if cv2.waitKey(1)==27:
            break
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
cap.release()
```

Comment: ¿Puedes poner en tu pregunta el error completo que te muestra Python? Por otro lado, ¿tu código es el que muestras en la pregunta o lo que has puesto es solo un extracto?

Comment: como observación mas que como solución, que tarda mucho en correr el código, parece que estás utilizado las variables `x, y` que creas en el primer loop lo utilizas en el segundo loop, por norma las variables que se crean dentro de un bucle no se pueden llamar desde fuera del bucle. Por eso salta el error de que `x`no está definida.

Comment: @montessillo No es correcta esta respuesta. Las variables creadas en un bucle son visibles también fuera del bucle. Pero creo que sí que hay algo relacionado con eso. El problema es seguramente que las variables `x`,`y` están dentro de un `if`. Si la condición es falsa y el `if` no se ejecuta, esas variables no se crean y por eso no se pueden usar después.

Comment: Si, por ahora ese es todo mi código , el error dice así  
,line 78, in <module>
    cv2.line(frame,(x, y), (x1, y1),(0, 255, 0), 1, cv2.LINE_AA)

NameError: name 'x' is not defined

Comment: Muchísimas gracias haré un intento añadiendole la condicion para el false n.n